# Why is an 8 month old question considered "Active" in review queues?

Tags: support, flags, last-activity

I notice a lot of questions that I've flagged still showing with an `Active` badge in review history, even though the questions themselves have not been active for a while.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000937/version-of-windows-installer-iso) was asked on August 13, 2013, and is shown as being last active 8 months ago on the question page itself, but is showing up with an `Active` badge in review history.

Comment: You mean the **flag** is still active? That's not the question itself being active..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, perhaps I should have been more clear. Why is the flag still active when the question is not? I didn't realize they meant different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'active' indicator in your flag history applies to the *flag itself*; it just means the flag has not yet been handled by a moderator and is thus still active.

It has no correlation to the 'active' label on the question page itself.